# How to create android live wallpaper using unity3d?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, live-wallpaper

As written in the title, I'm trying to create an android live wallpaper using unity3d. Unfortunately, I can't find any information on how to do that.

Comment: [pls help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63709936/how-exactly-do-i-render-metal-on-a-background-thread)­

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, trials and errors, I finally managed to make it work. For those who are interested in running or trying to create Android live wallpapers on Unity3D I created a GitHub [Unity3dAndroidLiveWallpaper](https://github.com/MartinRGB/Unity3dAndroidLiveWallpaper) project that you can use as a base for your own projects. I only tested this project on **Unity 2018.3.5f1**, but any versions above **2018.3** should work, because since that version Unity allows you to add **.java** files into your Unity project and they are compiled when you build an Android player. Because of that Android Studio is not required to compile this project.

[image]

Comment: The sample project link leads to a GitHub profile, not a repo, and I cannot find the repo on the profile.